# Function in Pivot View

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2008, view, pivot

This **VIEW** working fine

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    ....
    ) T1
    PIVOT
    (SUM(TOTAL) FOR Sales IN ( [S1],[S2],[S3])) piv
```

The problem when using the Function result for Dynamic PIVOT columns
Like:

```
(SUM(TOTAL) FOR Sales IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.myFUNCTION())) piv
```

The Function result is

```
[S1],[S2],[S3],[S8],[S10]
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't execute dynamic SQL in user defined functions.  Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.